# How to get mesh center in babylonjs?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

After double clicking on a mesh I need to find out what is the centre of the mesh regarding to its boundary box

```
    window.addEventListener("dblclick", function (event) {
        var pickResult = scene.pick(scene.pointerX, scene.pointerY);
        var mesh = pickResult.pickedMesh;
        //var centerPosition = mesh.GetCenter(); <-- what is the center             
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the mesh, you can call mesh.getBoundingInfo

On a bounding info object you have a bounding box and a bounding sphere. The sphere provides the mesh center in local and world coordinates

http://doc.babylonjs.com/api/classes/babylon.boundinginfo